# How to use batch file to launch cmd silently?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use my batch script to call upon a cmd to uninstall a program.

> install -u

Is there a way which I can use my batch script to execute this cmd silently? Meaning it wont pop up.

Thanks!

Comment: What is an `install -u`? Does this command removes `%Windir%`? Or does this install some new things?

Answer (score 0):

```
start /min install -u
```

or if it's a command-line program

```
start /min cmd /c install -u
```